# MySQL 5.x - Can you explain this weirdness?

Tags: mysql, operator-keyword, negate

Running the query ...

```
SELECT !(!0), ! !0, !!0 AS WTF;
```

in MySQL yields the following output ...

```
-------------------------
  !(!0) |  ! !0  |  WTF  
-------------------------
     0  |    0    |  1     # <- What's going on here?
```

I can't seem to find anything in the Docs that would explain this. Can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a known [bug in mysql](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55477) regarding operator parsing.

Comment: As a workaround you should use `NOT` instead of `!`. It's functionally equivalent, but it will avoid that bug because it forces you to put spaces between multiple operators, for example: `SELECT NOT (NOT 0), NOT  NOT 0, NOT NOT 0 AS WTF;`

Comment: Thanks Mat! @Ike Walker Not quite, the precedence of both `NOT` and `!` only happens to be the same when SQL mode [HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_high_not_precedence) is enabled!

Comment: btw, I did the "!!" -> "not not" conversion to find that bug report in google :-)